# Unknown cause of seaborn.violinplot() KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I'm creating an exploratory data analysis for the House Prices competition on Kaggle, and ran into a problem with the `seaborn.violinplot()` function:

I want to plot `LotFrontage` with the function, but I get the following error:

```
sns.violinplot(data=houseprices_num['LotFrontage'], inner='quartile', color='white')
```

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-01b815903af9> in <module>
      1 #houseprices_lfnotna = houseprices[houseprices['LotFrontage'].notna()]
----> 2 sns.violinplot(data=houseprices_num['LotFrontage'], inner='quartile', color='white')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\_decorators.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     44             )
     45         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 46         return f(**kwargs)
     47     return inner_f
     48 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in violinplot(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize, width, inner, split, dodge, orient, linewidth, color, palette, saturation, ax, **kwargs)
   2385 ):
   2386 
-> 2387     plotter = _ViolinPlotter(x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order,
   2388                              bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize,
   2389                              width, inner, split, dodge, orient, linewidth,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in __init__(self, x, y, hue, data, order, hue_order, bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize, width, inner, split, dodge, orient, linewidth, color, palette, saturation)
    520                  color, palette, saturation):
    521 
--> 522         self.establish_variables(x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order)
    523         self.establish_colors(color, palette, saturation)
    524         self.estimate_densities(bw, cut, scale, scale_hue, gridsize)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\categorical.py in establish_variables(self, x, y, hue, data, orient, order, hue_order, units)
     96                 if hasattr(data, "shape"):
     97                     if len(data.shape) == 1:
---> 98                         if np.isscalar(data[0]):
     99                             plot_data = [data]
    100                         else:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    880 
    881         elif key_is_scalar:
--> 882             return self._get_value(key)
    883 
    884         if is_hashable(key):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _get_value(self, label, takeable)
    987 
    988         # Similar to Index.get_value, but we do not fall back to positional
--> 989         loc = self.index.get_loc(label)
    990         return self.index._get_values_for_loc(self, loc, label)
    991 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

Previous modifications done on `houseprices_num` that might, but not probably, be responsible for the error:

```
traindf = pd.read_csv('.\\train.csv', sep=',', header=1, index_col='Id')
testdf = pd.read_csv('.\\test.csv', sep=',', header=0, index_col='Id')
houseprices = pd.concat([traindf, testdf], axis=0)
houseprices_num = houseprices[['LotFrontage', 'LotArea', 'MasVnrArea', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'BsmtFinSF2', 'BsmtUnfSF',
                              'TotalBsmtSF', '1stFlrSF', '2ndFlrSF', 'LowQualFinSF', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageArea', 'WoodDeckSF', 'OpenPorchSF', 'EnclosedPorch',
                              '3SsnPorch', 'ScreenPorch', 'PoolArea', 'MiscVal', 'SalePrice']]
```

From the error message, I suspected that the `inner=` kwarg could be responsible, but according to the seaborn documentation, `'quartile'` is a valid argument. I also tried plotting `LotFrontage` without the null values with no success.

I would appreciate an explanation of this error, and how to fix it.
Thanks!

Comment: confirm that your your concatenation of the traindf and testdf worked.  The error message is telling you that the shape is incorrect.

Comment: houseprices has 2919 rows, that is equal to rows of traindf (1460) + rows of testdf (1459)

Comment: houseprices also has 80 columns, just like traindf

Answer (score 0):

the violinplot receives numeric data.  you provide the x and y variables to be plotted.

```
 sns.violinplot(data=houseprices_num,y="LoadFrontageDRG Definition", x="LotArea")
 plt.show()

 #or for one violin plot

 sns.violinplot(houseprices_num["LoadFrontageDRG Definition"])

 plt.show()
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want 1 violin to look at the distribution of this column, you can do:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
sns.violinplot(data=houseprices_num['LotFrontage'].values, 
inner='quartile', color='white')
```

[image]

I think if you call in the dataframe it is causing some problems. If you want to make the violin plot wrt to other categories, you can do for example:

```
houseprices_num['GarageArea_bin'] = pd.cut(houseprices_num['GarageArea'],2,
labels=['A','B'])
sns.violinplot(data=houseprices_num,x='GarageArea_bin',y='LotFrontage',
inner='quartile', color='white')
```

[image]